# flylatex dosen't find all modules

Tags: javascript, node.js

If I run flylatex from github, get the following Error on Debian and Ubuntu. Is my nodejs stuff broken or has flylatex a error? At first I run `npm install -d` in the working directory. My version of nodejs is 0.10.25. The last output is `npm info ok` Has anyone an idea for fixing the problem?

```
rennecke@odin ~/flylatex ±master » nodejs app.js 
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module './src'
  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
  at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
  at require (module.js:380:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/home/rennecke/flylatex/node_modules/share/index.js:2:18)
  at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
  at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
  at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
  at require (module.js:380:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/home/rennecke/flylatex/app.js:10:13)
  at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
  at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
  at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
  at startup (node.js:119:16)
  at node.js:902:3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem.
It's a "`nodejs and coffee script`" problem.
You have to find a way to explain to "`nodejs`" how to "compile on the fly" coffee script.

I was not able to find the solution but, on my side, the `./node_modules/share/src` of coeffeescript was already compile in javascript in the `./node_moudules/share/lib`

So I just edit the file :

```
./node_modules/share/index.js

comment the 2 lines
// require ('coffee-script');
// module.exports = require('./src'):
```

and add the line

```
module.exports = require('./lib');
```

And it's work.

I am still looking for a more "elegant" solution for a "one line" compilation of coffescript.

hope this helps.